# Parametrising the surface enclosed by a parametric curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric, surface-integrals

I have a curve given by $(\cos t, \sin t, \sin 2t)$ with $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$:

[image]

I need to integrate a function over any of the infinitely many surfaces to which this curve is a boundary. How would I find a parametrised form of such a surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that 
$$z(t)=\sin 2t = 2\sin (t) \cos (t)=2x(t)y(t)$$
Therefore, a possible surface is
$$
z=2xy, \quad x=x, \quad y=y\quad \mbox{with}\quad x^2+y^2\le 1
$$

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it! Is there a general template formula for finding surfaces, or does it just depend on spotting things like that?

Comment: Nope, typically in these questions you have to spot it. But typically it is quite easy to spot once you know the methodology!

Comment: Also, you might want to write the equation in polar coordinates since $x^2+y^2\le 1$, it kind of depends what you need to do on this surface.